# Creating a slider with dots representing each image, each not returning image element?

Tags: jquery

Javascript:

```
var images = $('#slideshow').children();

var dot_holder = $('#slider_dots');
/* Create the dots*/

images.each(function(index,item){

    if(item.hasClass('active')){
        dot_holder.append('<img src="Images/dot_solid.png" alt=""/>');
    }else{
        dot_holder.append('<img src="Images/dot_fade.png" alt=""/>');
    }


});
```

html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
                    <img src="Images/image_1.jpg" alt="image 1" class="active"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_2.jpg" alt="image 2"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_3.jpg" alt="image 3"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_4.jpg" alt="image 4"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_5.jpg" alt="image 5"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_6.jpg" alt="image 6"/>
                    <img src="Images/image_7.jpg" alt="image 7"/>


                </div>
```

Essentially, I want the dot to be solid representing the active image, however I get an error saying Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'hasClass'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.hasClass('active')
```

should be:

```
$(item).hasClass('active')
```

Because through iteration you have direct reference to the element, and `hasClass` is function of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Write `$(item)` instead to get a jquery object.